# Understanding and using Bertini's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to use Bertini's theorem for a linear system $|D|$ in a smooth projective variety $X$. I know the definitions that are necessary to understand what Bertini's theorem says, for a less general case as I have described above. However, I have read Bertini's theorem in "Principles of Algebraic Geometry-Phillips Griffiths and Joe Harris", where it is written as follows:

Bertini's Theorem: The generic element of a linear system is smooth away from the base locus of the system.

Seeking an alternative, perhaps more detailed, statement I found:

Theorem (Bertini): Let $X$ be a smooth complex variety
and let $|D|$ be a positive dimensional linear system
on $X$. Then the general element of $|D|$ is smooth away
from the base locus $B_{|D|}$. That is, the set
$$
\{H \in |D| \,|\, D_{H} \,\text {is smooth away from} \,B_{D} \}
$$
is a Zariski dense open subset of |D|.

Now comes my stupid question, which means: $|D|$ be a positive dimensional linear system?

Linear system, ok! But, positive dimensional,
would simply be dim$|D|$>$0$???

Comment: Yes, you need at least two generators  for $|D|$.

Comment: Koé, @AlanMuniz! Valeu mlk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely read Chapter II, Section 7 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry ([here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/229795203/Algebraic-Geometry-Hartshorne)). It gives you the definition of the dimension of a linear system (page 157). Briefly: a linear system corresponds to a sub-vector space of the global sections of some invertible sheaf; the non-zero global sections of an invertible sheaf modulo $k^*$ can be viewed as the set of closed points of a projective space, and so a linear system corresponds to a linear projective variety in this projective space, and its dimension is the dimension of this projective variety.